# Thunderbird uses imap account not shown in settings

Tags: thunderbird

In Thunderbird, I get an error message coming from a server I didn't set up.

The error message is

```
"Timeout occured retrieving data from imap.tset.com."
```

I searched through each and every account in Thunderbird settings, but I just don't see any reference to it.

How could I debug where this server setting might be stored within Thunderbird if it isn't accessible via the settings menu?

Comment: The domain `tset.com` is apparently for sale, so has nothing. The reference might rather be in some email you are receiving and not from an email account.

Comment: Sounds like one of the emails has a payload of nasties.

Comment: @harrymc The error message occurs when I start up Thunderbird, not when I open up a mail.

Comment: Did you checked SMTP accounts?